# No me ejecuta Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, yarn, nuxt

estoy intentando ejecutar una carpeta de nuxt con yarn run dev y me aparece esto[image]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.